# Is it possible to listen for "ipconfig" changes on Windows?

Tags: java, c++, ip, listener, ipconfig

I need to execute some code when IP address associated with "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" is changed. I thought may be it is not so good to check every N seconds/minutes for changes manually and there is something like "listener" that will execute my code as soon as changes was made. Do you know something about it? Or is it impossible and I need just check sometimes for changes? I'm considering Java or C++ (Java is much more suitable for me). Thanks :)

Comment: A DNS suffix is **not** associated with an IP address nor an IP range. E.g. our company's DNS suffix is used both for on-premise machines as well as machines in a datacenter at our provider, and our mail server is at yet another location.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366334(v=vs.85).aspx
Highlights 2 functions you can use in C++

1. NotifyAddrChange
2. NotifyRouteChange

Not knowing exactly what change you're looking for, I leave it to you to read up about them.